# flutter TexteditingController not working on ios

Tags: flutter

TextEditingController is not working on ios, the texts gets cleared when you type. On android is working. I saw someone else also got this problem, but they fixed it when they put the textEditingController inside the stateful widget. My problem is that I need default text in my texteditingcontroller and the deafult text is coming from a provider class, so I need context to get it working.

```
final GameSpecs gameSpecs = Provider.of<GameSpecs>(context); 
final mySecondController = gameSpecs.questionIndex != null
        ? TextEditingController(
            text: gameSpecs.questions[gameSpecs.questionIndex])
        : TextEditingController();
```

what should I do to get it to work on Ios?

Answer (score 1):

You should NOT initialize controllers in stateless widgets since it will lead to memory leaks and unexpected behaviours almost always.

For this you should use a stateful widget. The problem about context is easily solvable , you can get the context inside initState then get the provider using the context. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61865011/10205629) for a working example.